# Problems with cross-language HMAC / SHA256 / Base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, base64, hmac

I'm using a node.js script to create a signature for azure documentDB - the simplified version is (result at the bottom):-

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var masterKey = "ABCDE"
var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");
var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update("FGHIJ").digest("base64");

console.log("\n\n"+signature)

// RNkID54/1h1H9p3NWPeRA0mOW2L0c0HUJGTTY2GPbDo=
```

This works, and does what I need it to. I'm trying to do the same thing in Swift with CommonCrypto

```
let keyString = "ABCDE"
let body = "FGHIJ"

let utf8data = keyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let key = utf8data!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

let str = body.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let strLen = body.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let digestLen = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)

CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), key.bytes, key.length, str!, strLen, result);

var hmacData = NSData(bytes: result, length: digestLen)
var hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

result.dealloc(digestLen)

let signature = String(hmacBase64)

let test = "RNkID54/1h1H9p3NWPeRA0mOW2L0c0HUJGTTY2GPbDo="
XCTAssert(test == signature, "Pass")
```

But it returns a completely different result. If I pass the masterKey directly into the javascript hmac, and pass it in as a string into the CCHmac method in Swift, it all works; so it seems to be something to do with finding the equivalent to this:-

```
var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");
```

Thoughts?

---

More information - this:-

```
let keyString = "ABCDE"
let body = "FGHIJ"

let keyData = keyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! // .base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
let bodyData = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

let digestLen = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)

CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), keyData.bytes, keyData.length, bodyData.bytes, bodyData.length, result);

var hmacData = NSData(bytes: result, length: digestLen)
var hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

result.dealloc(digestLen)

let signature = String(hmacBase64)

let test = "FA372zbobgpTLI5cQWh5YFiFwkNhMI8womX4Cvw68YE=" // "RNkID54/1h1H9p3NWPeRA0mOW2L0c0HUJGTTY2GPbDo="
XCTAssert(test == signature, "Pass")
```

Produces the same result as this:-

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var masterKey = "ABCDE"
var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", masterKey).update("FGHIJ").digest("base64");

console.log("\n\n"+signature)

// FA372zbobgpTLI5cQWh5YFiFwkNhMI8womX4Cvw68YE=
```

Comment: You can find a working solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561203/accessing-azure-table-storage-from-swift/34568460?noredirect=1#comment56881435_34568460