# Accessing Azure Table Storage from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http, azure, authentication

I want to access the azure table storage from Swift. 
The instruction for making the header is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx)
However, I have tried to build the request but can't make it work:

```
 let urlString =   "https://<myaccount>.table.core.windows.net/MyTable"
    let storageUrl = NSURL( string: urlString)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: storageUrl!)

    //making the date
    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let httpFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    httpFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
    httpFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss z"
    let httpTime = httpFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
    print(httpTime)

    let signingString = "GET\n\n\n\(httpTime)\n/<myaccount>/MyTable"
    print(signingString)


    let keyString = <myKeyString>
    let keyData = keyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let signingData = signingString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let length:Int = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let hashResult = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(length)
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), keyData.bytes, Int(keyData.length), signingData.bytes, Int(signingData.length), hashResult)
    print(hashResult)
    let hash = NSData(bytes: hashResult, length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    let hashString = hash.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions([]))
    hashResult.destroy()
    //print(hashString)

    request.setValue("SharedKeyLite <myaccount>:\(hashString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(httpTime, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-ms-date")
    request.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "Date")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            let datastring = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print( datastring! )

            //print(response)

        } else {

            print( error )

        }
    }).resume()
```

After the correct answer below, I made an extension to the String, so the hmac signing is very easy to do:

```
//
//  CryptoExtensions.swift
//  LaochTestProject
//
//  Created by Lars Christoffersen on 02/01/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Lars Christoffersen. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation


    enum CryptoAlgorithm {
        case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

        var HMACAlgorithm: CCHmacAlgorithm {
            var result: Int = 0
            switch self {
            case .MD5:      result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
            case .SHA1:     result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
            case .SHA224:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
            case .SHA256:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
            case .SHA384:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
            case .SHA512:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
            }
            return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
        }

        var digestLength: Int {
            var result: Int32 = 0
            switch self {
            case .MD5:      result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
            case .SHA1:     result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
            case .SHA224:   result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
            case .SHA256:   result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
            case .SHA384:   result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
            case .SHA512:   result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
            }
            return Int(result)
        }
    }

    extension String {

        func hmac(algorithm: CryptoAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {


            let strData = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
            let keyData = NSData(base64EncodedString: key, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!
            let digestLen = algorithm.digestLength
            let hashResult = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)
            CCHmac(algorithm.HMACAlgorithm, keyData.bytes, Int(keyData.length), strData.bytes, Int(strData.length), hashResult)
            let hash = NSData(bytes: hashResult, length: digestLen )
            let hashString = hash.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions([]))
            hashResult.destroy()
            return hashString
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not an iOS developer (so I wouldn't know how you would do it) but I noticed that you are converting the account key string to `NSData` object using UTF8 Encoding. Please note that the key is a Base64 encoded string. In .Net world, we do something like `Convert.FromBase64String(key)` to get the byte array. Can you try by doing something similar in your code?

Comment: Hi That is happening here let hashString = hash.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions([])) so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you be the doing the same thing here as well ... `let keyData = keyString.dataUsingEncoding...`? I know that in .Net if we get the byte array using UTF8, we always get error.

Comment: Ahh see what you mean. I'll check it out thanks for the hint

Comment: No it is done the right way. The instruction says: "and Signature is a Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) constructed from the request and computed by using the SHA256 algorithm, and then encoded by using Base64 encoding." which is what I am doing (I hope)

Comment: Installing Xcode right now (it was long overdue anyways :)) .... let me give it a try.

Comment: OK. Just remember when using swift you have to make a bridging header file for the C Crypto Library and #import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h> Otherwise the CCHmac functions will not be available for you :-) Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working :)

Here's my code which lists all tables in an Azure Storage account:

```
//
//  main.swift
//  Azure Storage REST Helper
//
//  Created by Gaurav Mantri on 1/2/16.
//

import Foundation
let accountName = "{account-name}"
let urlString = "https://{account-name}.table.core.windows.net/Tables"
let storageUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: storageUrl!)
let currentDate = NSDate()
let httpFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
httpFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
httpFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss z"
let httpTime = httpFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
print(httpTime)

let signingString = "GET\n\n\n\(httpTime)\n/{account-name}/Tables"
print(signingString)
let keyString = "{account-key}"
let keyData = NSData(base64EncodedString: keyString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!

let signingData = signingString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
let length:Int = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
let hashResult = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(length)
CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), keyData.bytes, Int(keyData.length), signingData.bytes, Int(signingData.length), hashResult)
print(hashResult)
let hash = NSData(bytes: hashResult, length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
let hashString = hash.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions([]))
hashResult.destroy()

print(hashString)

request.setValue("SharedKey {account-name}:\(hashString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

request.setValue(httpTime, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-ms-date")
request.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "Date")

request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
print("comes here")
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        let datastring = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print( datastring! )
        print("comes here 1")
        //print(response)

    } else {
        print("comes here 2")
        print( error )

    }
}).resume()
```

A few things that I did:

- Instead of using UTF8 encoding to get `keyData`, I created `NSData` using `base64Encoding`.
- I got rid of `Content-Type` header so the result is returned in XML. If you want to return data in JSON format, please specify `Accept` header instead of `Content-Type` header.
- You were creating signature using `SharedKey` scheme yet you specified `SharedKeyLite` in the `Authorization` header. I changed that to `SharedKey`.

Oh, and please don't judge the code and feel free to edit it. I know this is not the best code :)

Comment: Please look at the 3 bullet points in my response. Those were causing the error. I simply fixed those.

Comment: Yeah I saw them now. Sorry. But you have been a great help, and the first one on the internet to solve this :-) I have seen quite a few posts with the same problem.

Comment: If I could I would give you a lot more points! I was really stuck in this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I am glad that I was able to help you out (bonus for me was coding in Swift). Please answer other unanswered questions (or point them here) so that others can benefit as well.