# Using Azure Table Storage (NoSQL) in ios app swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, azure, azure-storage

Can anyone help me with how can I use Azure table storage which is a NoSQL storage, I am aware of how to use blobs but I am unable to find any way to use tables?

Comment: What have you done to try and make this work, where are you having problems? There are lots of articles out there on doing this.

Comment: @SamCogan can you give me the link of an article for the same n swift?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561203/accessing-azure-table-storage-from-swift

Comment: @SamCogan Their is no clarity in that answer, I am unable to understand thats why I posted here, can u help me?

Comment: You have not provided any details of what your issue is, what is your particular issue?

Comment: @SamCogan My issue is i am unable to connect with azure table storage as azure mobile app allows sql database connectivity and azure table storage is nosql ,

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native Azure iOS SDK that supports Azure Table Storage. Your best bet is to use the REST API.