# Azure Storage REST API POST request

Tags: swift, rest, post, azure-table-storage

I am trying to write a POST request in Swift 5 using CryptoKit and following the AccessKey scheme for Azure Storage -> [Table Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) -> [`Insert Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity) but I am getting a 403 [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-error-codes) with a failed authentication response and I suspect I'm not forming the signature correctly. In particular I'm uncertain the base64 encoding of the HMAC<SHA256> result is correct.

I messed with the headers as a test and the server replied with a 400 error instead of the 403, which I think confirms the issue is with the signature. The nearest [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561203/accessing-azure-table-storage-from-swift) I've found is from 2016 which I haven't been able to translate successfully to Swift 5 using CryptoKit.

```
class DataService: ObservableObject{
    let requestURI: String = "https://MYACCOUNT.table.core.windows.net/TABLENAME"
    let xmsVersion: String = "2021-12-02"
    //let dataServiceVersion: String = "3.0;NetFx"
    
    let accessKey: String = "accesskey"
    var verb: String = "POST"
    let contentType: String = "application/json"
    let canonicalizedResource: String = "/MYACCOUNT/TABLENAME"
    
    
    //GENERATE REQUEST
    private func generateRequest() -> URLRequest{
        let url = URL(string: requestURI)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let date = getDate()
        
        //AUTHORIZATION HEADER
        let authorizationHeader = generateAuthorizationHeader(date: date)
        print("Authorization: ", authorizationHeader)
        
        request.httpMethod = verb
        request.addValue(authorizationHeader, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue(date, forHTTPHeaderField: "Date")
        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue(xmsVersion, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-ms-version")
        request.addValue(String(getEncodedDataTest().count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        
        //request.addValue(date, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-ms-date")
        //request.addValue(dataServiceVersion, forHTTPHeaderField: "DataServiceVersion")
        //request.addValue(maxDataServiceVersion, forHTTPHeaderField: "MaxDataServiceVersion")
        
        request.httpBody = getJSON()
        
        return request
    }
    
    //SEND REQUEST
    func sendRequest(){
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = generateRequest()
        
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: request.httpBody!, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
            print("\(data)")
            print ("\nRESPONSE:\n\(response)")
            print("\(error)")
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    
    private func generateKey() -> SymmetricKey {
        let decodedKey = Data(base64Encoded: accessKey, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
        
        return SymmetricKey(data: decodedKey)
    }
    
    private func generateAuthorizationHeader(date: String) -> String{
        let key = generateKey() //Access Key
        
        let signatureString = verb+"\n"+accessKey+"\n"+contentType+"\n"+date+"\n"+canonicalizedResource

        let signingData = signatureString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

        let signature = HMAC<SHA256>.authenticationCode(for: Data(signingData), using: key)
        
        let signatureData = signature.withUnsafeBytes { code in
            return Data(bytes: code.baseAddress!, count: signature.byteCount)
        }
        
        let encodedSignature: String = signatureData.base64EncodedString()
        print("encodedSignature:", "\(encodedSignature)")

        return "SharedKey MYACCOUNT:\(encodedSignature)"
    }

    private func getDate() -> String{
        let date = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        let httpDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        print("Date:", httpDate)
        return httpDate
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error is due to an incorrect StringtoSign used for framing the Authorization header.

Documentation for how to form the StringToSign for *Table service* is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#table-service-shared-key-authorization).

The process to generate the SharedKey Signature is mentioned below:

1. Construct the String to Sign.
2. Decode the Base64 storage key.
3. Use the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm and the decoded storage key from previous step to compute a hash of the string to sign
4. Base64 encode the hash and include this in the Authorization header

Syntax:
Signature=Base64(HMAC-SHA256(UTF8(StringToSign), Base64.decode(<your_azure_storage_account_shared_key>)))

Hope this helps.